# SQL: Get latest entries from history table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 3 tables

```
person (id, name)
area (id, number)
history (id, person_id, area_id, type, datetime)
```

In this tables I store the info which person had which area at a specific time. It is like a salesman travels in an area for a while and then he gets another area. He can also have multiple areas at a time.

history type = 'I' for CheckIn or 'O' for Checkout.
Example:

```
id    person_id    area_id    type    datetime
1     2            5          'O'     '2011-12-01' 
2     2            5          'I'     '2011-12-31' 
A person started traveling in area 5 at 2011-12-01 and gave it back on 2011-12-31.
```

Now I want to have a list of all the areas all persons have right now.

```
person1.name, area1.number, area2.number, area6.name
person2.name, area5.number, area9.number
....
```

The output could be like this too (it doesn't matter):

```
person1.name, area1.number
person1.name, area2.number
person1.name, area6.number
person2.name, area5.number
....
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you're looking for a list of people who currently have an area checked out and haven't checked it back in yet?

Comment: I'm going to personally recommend against storing `type` as a `char` value (or at least, on it's lonesome) - store it as a fk reference to a table detailing what that value _means_ (like your `person` and `area` tables).  This restricts entries to valid values, which can (easily) be updated at any time, without the need for `alter` statements... among other things.

Comment: Presumably the id = 1 in the second line of the history example data is a typo and it should be 2 or some other number?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are right. I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is, indeed, quite tricky.  You need a list of the entries in history where, for a given user and area, there is an 'O' record with no subsequent 'I' record.  Working with just the history table, that translates to:

```
SELECT ho.person_id, ho.area_id, ho.type, MAX(ho.datetime)
  FROM History AS ho
 WHERE ho.type = 'O'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM History AS hi
                   WHERE hi.person_id = ho.person_id
                     AND hi.area_id   = ho.area_id
                     AND hi.type = 'I'
                     AND hi.datetime > ho.datetime
                 )
 GROUP BY ho.person_id, ho.area_id, ho.type;
```

Then, since you're really only after the person's name and the area's number (though why the area number can't be the same as its ID I am not sure), you need to adapt slightly, joining with the extra two tables:

```
SELECT p.name, a.number
  FROM History AS ho
  JOIN Person  AS p  ON ho.person_id = p.id
  JOIN Area    AS a  ON ho.area_id   = a.id
 WHERE ho.type = 'O'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                    FROM History AS hi
                   WHERE hi.person_id = ho.person_id
                     AND hi.area_id   = ho.area_id
                     AND hi.type = 'I'
                     AND hi.datetime > ho.datetime
                 );
```

The NOT EXISTS clause is a correlated sub-query; that tends to be inefficient.  You might be able to recast it as a LEFT OUTER JOIN with appropriate join and filter conditions:

```
SELECT p.name, a.number
  FROM History AS ho
  JOIN Person  AS p  ON ho.person_id = p.id
  JOIN Area    AS a  ON ho.area_id   = a.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN History AS hi
    ON hi.person_id = ho.person_id
   AND hi.area_id   = ho.area_id
   AND hi.type = 'I'
   AND hi.datetime > ho.datetime
 WHERE ho.type = 'O'
   AND hi.person_id IS NULL;
```

All SQL unverified.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for results where each row may have a different number of columns? I think you may want to look into GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT p.`id`, GROUP_CONCAT(a.`number`, ',') AS `areas` FROM `person` a LEFT JOIN `history` h ON h.`person_id` = p.`id` LEFT JOIN `area` a ON a.`id` = h.`area_id`
```

I haven't tested this query, but I have used group concat in similar ways before. Naturally, you will want to tailor this to fit your needs. Of course, group concat will return a string so it will require post processing to use the data.

**EDIT** I thikn your question has been edited since I began responding. My query does not really fit your request anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from person p
inner join history h on h.person_id = p.id
left outer join history h2 on h2.person_id = p.id and h2.area_id = h.area_id and h2.type = 'O'
inner join areas on a.id = h.area_id
where h2.person_id is null and h.type = 'I'
```

Comment: This won't work if a person has checked out an area once, checked it in, and then checked it out again. **Edit:** Perhaps adding `and h2.datetime > h.datetime` would fix that issue? I haven't thought it through yet.