# SQL - How to return entire row sets where some rows match a given list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say there is a table of medical records. Each visit has a unique ID but is made up of several rows corresponding to various codes/services rendered for the visit.
For example, there could be 3 rows with claimID "John" for each unique procedure code "123", "456", and "789"; 15 rows for "Jane" with codes; 6 rows for "David"...

```
ID      Code
John    123
John    456
John    789
Jane    123
Jane    456
Jane    789
Jane    321
Jane    654
David   123
David   456
David   789
David   987
```

I have a list of 50 unique procedure codes and want to return the entire **set** of claim lines (i.e. *all* rows of "John") where any combination of these 50 codes have been billed with another, but not with themselves ("123" with "321", but not "123" with "123").  If "123" is in my list of 50 but "456" and "789" are not, it should *not* return the set of "John" claims since only one code of my 50 are present.  I hope this makes sense.

```
Positive Result Codes
123
321
987
```

The query should return all 5 Jane rows (123 and 321) and all 4 David rows (123 & 987).

```
ID      Code
Jane    123
Jane    456
Jane    789
Jane    321
Jane    654
David   123
David   456
David   789
David   987
```

Comment: Please add example data and expected output in table form.

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new. I don't see any markdown for tables.

Comment: Here is a great article that explains how to post this type of stuff. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Use 4 spaces to make a line having code style. Or mark the lines and click the code button in the question editor. For instance see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8495886/575376

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
;WITH Visits as (
    SELECT claimID,COUNT(DISTINCT Code) as CNT FROM tbl_Visits
    WHERE Code in (123,123,321,987)
    GROUP by claimID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Code) > 1
)
SELECT * FROM tbl_Visits
WHERE claimID in (SELECT claimID FROM Visits);
```